# Looking for HTTP Authentication website examples

Tags: apache-flex, http, firefox, authentication

I am looking for a website that requires HTTP authentication, so I can observe the behaviour of typical HTTP authentication dialog boxes. The reason I am looking into this, is that for some reason, on Firefox 3, our Flex app seems to open another HTTP authentication dialog box again, after cancel is clicked. It only seems to happen in Firefox 3. I want to find out if this is just a Firefox 3 issue, the nature of HTTP authentication, or something is wrong with our Flex app.

EDIT: I should clarify some more details. The problem with our flex app, is that when the authentication dialog box appears, the user clicks cancel. Then attempts to enter the page again, causing the authentication dialog box to appear again. However, if they type the correct password, the *same* dialog will reappear.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This website offers an example of HTTP authentication: http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't seem to realize that when you enter a username and password for a site it should attempt that authentication on all subsequent frames before asking you to log in again.

I'm not sure why this is, it seems like a bug to me but perhaps there is good reason for it.

One way to get around it is to begin your site on a page without frames, once HTTP authentication is finished redirect them to the framed page.

Comment: It's possibly to protect against cross site script attacks, since the HTTP Basic Auth credentials are plain text.